# Occasionally receiving WarningContextClassLoader instead of PathClassLoader causing flyway to crash

Tags: java, android, classloader, flyway

**Context**

In my android app, I use **flyway** to update my Db schema. Up to now I have one and only one migration, that creates 3 tables. Simple and usual business for flyway. It does work very well... most of the time! Sometimes it crashes with this error (full stack hereunder):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.LoadedApk$WarningContextClassLoader
cannot be cast to dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
```

I have several questions related to that error :

- What is LoadedApk.WarningContextClassLoader ?
- Why is it sometimes used instead of dalvik.system.PathClassLoader ?
- Is it a bug in my app, in Android system or in Flyway ?

I also noticed that I can inject explicitely the classloader inside flyway (Flyway.setClassLoader() )

- How can I get for sure the right classloader ?

Note that I inject the Application Context in Flyway, not a particular activity's context.

**Versions**

I use org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.0.2

I noticed this problem in Android 4.2.2 (JellyBean, api level 17) and 4.4 (KitKat, api level 19). AFAIK, it never occured on higher versions.

**Stack trace**

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp.free.debug/com.mycompany.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.LoadedApk$WarningContextClassLoader cannot be cast to dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2306)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2358)
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$600 (ActivityThread.java:156)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1340)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
    android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:153)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5299)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:511)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:833)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:600)
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)

Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.LoadedApk$WarningContextClassLoader cannot be cast to dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
    org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.android.AndroidScanner.<init> (AndroidScanner.java:46)
    org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.Scanner.<init> (Scanner.java:38)
    org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute (Flyway.java:1353)
    org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.info (Flyway.java:1040)
    com.mycompany.db.FlywayHelper.info (FlywayHelper.java:54)
    com.mycompany.db.FlywayHelper.migrate (FlywayHelper.java:45)
    com.mycompany.db.GW2DatabaseHelper.migrate (GW2DatabaseHelper.java:56)
    com.mycompany.db.DbInit.initKeyGuild (DbInit.java:62)
    com.mycompany.db.DbInit.init (DbInit.java:42)
    com.mycompany.business.BootApp.boot (BootApp.java:79)
    com.mycompany.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:51)
    android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5122)
    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1081)
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2270)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2358)
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$600 (ActivityThread.java:156)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1340)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
    android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:153)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5299)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:511)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:833)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:600)
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

**Research update**

Although its purpose is not clear to me, LoadedApk.WarningContextClassLoader appears to be a valid class loader, and should then be supported by Flyway. A [pull request](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/1475) has been submitted.

In between, a workaround needs to be implemented, to inject the expected class loader:

```
private void injectClassLoader(Flyway flyway) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = flyway.getClassLoader();
    if (classLoader != null && !(classLoader instanceof PathClassLoader)){
        flyway.setClassLoader(classLoader.getParent());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is LoadedApk.WarningContextClassLoader ?
>
> Why is it sometimes used instead of dalvik.system.PathClassLoader ?

Not really sure, but the purpose of this specific class loader seems to warn the user that its package could be sharing its virtual machine with other packages. [More info here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/778ce48%5E!/), thanks to @orip.

> Is it a bug in my app, in Android system or in Flyway ?

Anyway the WarningContextClassLoader is still a valid class loader, and must be accepted by flyway. The cast made in AndroidScanner was just useless.

**Solution**

- The [bug is now fixed](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/1475) in [flyway 4.1](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/download).

Answer (score 1):

There's decent info the the [commit message adding WarningContextClassLoader](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/778ce48%5E!/). I would guess passing the activity's context may help.

Comment: No it doesn't. I checked (flyway is open-source), context is not used to grab classloader. Actually flyway just initialize its classloader like this: `private ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();` But thanks for sharing !